# How do I verify a collection of values is unique (contains no duplicates) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, collections, unique, ienumerable

Surely there is an easy way to verify a collection of values has no duplicates [using the default `Comparison` of the `collection`'s `Type`] in C#/.NET ? Doesn't have to be directly built in but should be short and efficient.

I've looked a lot but I keep hitting examples of using `collection.Count() == collection.Distinct().Count()` which for me is inefficient. I'm not interested in the result and want to bail out as soon as I detect a duplicate, should that be the case.

(I'd love to delete this question and/or its answer if someone can point out the duplicates)

Comment: Using `Distinct()` without a comparer *does* use the default comparison of the type. It's not clear what you dislike about the solution using `Distinct()`...

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated Q to indicate my problem with it (I dont want the result and want to stop right away). (Its a simple guard)

Comment: Right, that's a very different question.

Comment: Weeell actually, it's the same question clarified only tiny bit (the problem statement remains the same - have a look in the history) but sorry for the confusion :P

Comment: The difference in *clarity* is huge - originally there was basically no indication of what you didn't like about just using `Distinct().Count()`; the question was unanswerable. I'd say that's a major difference in problem statement.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow! I see even not atting you doesn't deter you from following up :D The title was/is "How do I verify a collection of values is unique in C#" and body said "verify a collection of values has no duplicates". Aside from saying "properly" or "most efficiently" or "the way Jon Skeet would do it", I didn't (and still don't) think it leaves much room for doubt. The context, which I should have included and may still do is missing though - this is as a guard clause. Right now it happens to be in a `Debug.Assert` but it may get converted to a proper guard clause to guarantee my invariants.

Comment: No, there's *absolutely* plenty of room for doubt, because the question already showed that you knew one way to implement it - but you didn't like it **for unstated reasons**, which made it impossible to work out what you were looking for. Those reasons were stated in the edit, at which point the question became answerable. Any time you ask a question saying, "I want to do X. I can do it with Y. Surely there's a way of doing X!" you need to specify what's wrong with Y.

Comment: @JonSkeet Now you put it that way, I can only say it's a fair cop! Must re-read the asking good questions (it's prob a FAQ in there :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, if you just want to get out as soon as the duplicate is found, it's simple:

```
// TODO: add an overload taking an IEqualityComparer<T>
public bool AllUnique<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    var distinctItems = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!distinctItems.Add(item))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

... or use `All`, as you've already shown. I'd argue that this is slightly simpler to understand in this case... or if you *do* want to use `All`, I'd at least separate the creation of the set from the method group conversion, for clarity:

```
public static bool IsUnique<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    // TODO: validation
    var distinctItems = new HashSet<T>();
    // Add will return false if the element already exists. If
    // every element is actually added, then they must all be unique.
    return source.All(distinctItems.Add);
}
```

Comment: @RubenBartelink: I hadn't when I started writing mine, no. Nor did I notice that you were going to self-answer.

Comment: @RubenBartelink: I didn't spot it because I was busy being confused about the question itself, which is the problem. Anyway, having a couple of answers which emphasize different aspects does no harm.

Comment: Removed all my comments to tidy stuff. Accepted as the comments in the extension method are important and I took them.

Answer (score 7):

Doing it inline, you can replace:

```
collection.Count() == collection.Distinct().Count()
```

with

```
collection.All( new HashSet<T>().Add );
```

(where `T` is the type of your collection's elements)

Or you can extract the above to a helper extension method[1] so you can say:

```
collection.IsUnique()
```

[1]

```
static class EnumerableUniquenessExtensions
{
    public static bool IsUnique<T>(this IEnumerable<T> that)
    {
        return that.All( new HashSet<T>().Add );
    }
}
```

(and as Jon has pointed out in his answer, one really should separate and comment the two lines as such 'cuteness' is generally Not A Good Idea)