# How to know if two arrays have at least one equal element (f#)

Tags: arrays, f#

I have a question about compare Arrays.
I have two arrays:

```
   let A = [|1;2;3;4;5|]
   let B = [|2;7|]
```

I want to now if they have at least one equal element. If they have return True.
I try with a function like this:

```
   let exists = Array.exists2 (fun elem1 elem2 -> elem1 = elem2)
   exists A B
```

In this case should return true.
But it have a problem because it's only work when the arrays have the same length. How could do a function that works with differents lengths?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721968/how-do-i-verify-a-collection-of-values-is-unique-contains-no-duplicates-in-c-s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be simpler:

```
let exists a b = (Set.ofArray a, Set.ofArray b) ||> Set.intersect |> (<>) Set.empty
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let exists a b = Array.exists (Set.ofArray a).Contains b
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to calculate the intersection of the two sets

```
let aset,bset = Set.ofArray A, set.ofArray B
Set.Intersect aset,bset |> Set.toSeq |> Seq.length |> function |0 -> false _ -> true
```